# Updating data on destroy with pygtk

Tags: pygtk, glade

I'm using glade and pygtk and I have a window with a treeview with a button that opens a dialog that creates a new entry for the treeview.  I want to update the treeview in the main window when the dialog is destroyed but I can't see a simple way to do this.

--Edit--

Found the answer, I just needed to connect the windows destroy signal

```
(dialog).window.connect('destroy', self.foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach is to handle the response of the dialog in the main window:

```
def on_menu_item_activated(self, widget, data=None):
    dialog = FunkyDialog()
    response = dialog.run()

    if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
        // update treeview
```

Perhaps a better way of doing this would be to use the [Observer design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). When the user presses Ok, you save your data. This notifies the treeview that a change has been made, which causes it to reload.